# Trouble getting same results with ANOVA and multilevel model in R

Tags: regression, anova, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have read this paper about fitting ANOVA models as multilevel models:

https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1112967698

After reading it, I was trying to figure out how I could fit a basic ANOVA model with only 1 predictor as a multilevel model in R. However, I couldn't seem to get the same results. Here's a an example I tried to reproduce:

https://www.r-bloggers.com/one-way-analysis-of-variance-anova/

First, prep the data:

```
#Data
plant.df = PlantGrowth
# Factor
plant.df$group = factor(plant.df$group,
                    labels = c("Control", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 2"))
```

Second, fit ANOVA models in two different ways to make sure I get the same results:

```
# Method 1 -----------------------------------
# Make mod
plant.mod1 = lm(weight ~ group, data = plant.df)
# Anova of mod
anova(plant.mod1) # p ~ .02

# Method 2 -----------------------------------
# Make mod
plant.mod2 = lm(weight ~ 1, data = plant.df)
# Anova of mod
anova(plant.mod1,plant.mod2) # p ~ .02
```

Now fit a multilevel model in R and test if significant random effect (i.e., difference across group means):

```
 # Method 3 -----------------------------------
 # load lme4
 require(lme4)
 require(lmerTest)
 # Make mod
 plant.mod3 = lmer(weight ~ (1|group), data = plant.df,REML=F)
 rand(plant.mod3) # p ~ .06
```

For some reason I'm not getting the same p-values. However, my understanding was that multilevel models should yield the same results. Is there same way to get the identical p-values from the third method as I found with the first two methods?

**UPDATE: Perhaps the larger p-values occurs in Method 3 because of [shrinkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrinkage_estimator)?**

Comment: I think the issue is that these data are not multilevel (e.g., there is no clustering or repeated measurement). This is a simple fixed effects model. You could estimate it with ANOVA or simple OLS regression and get the same results. Also, I'm not sure why you are doing Method 2 above. It is simply reproducing the p-value for the single main effect of model 1.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue - the examples in the paper aren't "multilevel" per se (unless the paper is not correct). Method 3 just allows there to be group specific means (which is basically the idea of ANOVA, no?). I did Method 2 just to prove to myself that I could get the same results in different ways.

Comment: But in model 1 there is no random effect. If you specify the fixed effect of group (model 1) as a random effect, it will not agree with model 1 because you are estimating something different. Your second link is simply a fixed-effects one-way ANOVA.

Comment: You might be more successful working from a repeated measures ANOVA model with a fixed treatment effect (e.g., two or three measurement time points with two groups, treatment and control). These can be estimated via both ANOVA and mixed effects regression modeling.

Comment: I don't think that it needs to have a time component necessarily. That is, what's the difference in having participants nested across time opposed to nested across some other factor (like sex or ethnicity)? Here's another example of fitting an ANOVA as a multilevel model that doesn't involve time: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstanarm/vignettes/aov.html. I'm still not quite sure why I'm getting different results though.

Comment: The larger p-value in method 3 is because it is a random effect whereas in method 1 it is a fixed effect.